# Создание и совмещение регулярных выражений. Angular

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, typescript, angular

У меня есть два регулярных выражения

```
readonly linkRegExp = /(?: |^)(https?\:\/\/[-+a-zA-ZА-Яа-я0-9/%=~_|$?!:,.()&@#]+)/g;
readonly hyperlinkRegExp = /\[(.+?)\]\((https?:\/\/[-+a-zA-ZА-Яа-я0-9/%=~_|$?!:,.()&@#]+?)\)/g;
```

linkRegExp я использую для проверки обычных ссылок.

hyperlinkRegExp я использую для проверки гиперссылок форматом `[*](*)`.

Требуется переделать регулярное выражение hyperlinkRegExp, чтобы совмещать его с linkRegExp и использовать следующим образом:

```
const hyperlinkRegex = new RegExp(this.hyperlinkRegExp.source + this.linkRegExp.source);
text = text.replace(hyperlinkRegex, `<a href="$2" target="_blank">$1</a>`);
```

Необходимо сохранить проверку по формату гиперссылки `[*](*)`. У меня никак не получается изменить hyperlinkRegExp чтобы код выше срабатывал. Прошу помощи!

Comment: `const r = \`(${this.hyperlinkRegExp.source} | ${this.linkRegExp.source})\`;`?

Comment: @AlexanderChernin Спасибо за ответ! Мне нужно немного другое. Мне нужно, чтобы гиперссылка проверялась двумя регулярными выражениями сразу, одно чтобы проверяло что в квадратных скобка, а другое в круглых скобках `[ссылка на яндекс](https://ya.ru/)`. Я попробовал преобразовать иначе ваше предложение:

Comment: `readonly linkRegExp = /(https?:\/\/[-+a-zA-ZА-Яа-я0-9/%=~_|$?!:,.()&@#]+?)/g;` // должно находить ссылку т.е. https://ya.ru/

Comment: `readonly hyperlinkRegExp = /\[(.+?)\]/g;` // должно находить текст в квадратных скобках т.е. [Любой текст]

Comment: `const r = '${this.hyperlinkRegExp.source}(${this.linkRegExp.source})';`
`text = text.replace(r, '<a href="$2" target="_blank">$1</a>');`